# Angular 2/4 :How to use the existing component instance in a popup?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms, angular-components

I have component with selector 'test-comp' which is already loaded in a html page with code

analytics.html

```
<test-comp #refcomp ></test-comp>
```

I have a popup dialog in the same analytics.html page in which I would like show the same instance(#refcomp) instead of loading  it(test-comp) again.

-Currently I'm again creating one more instance

```
<test-comp #popup ></test-comp>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: can you explain your problem a bit clearly

Answer (score 1):

Actually, we have to render it twice.
But to fulfill your requirement, we can use a small hack.

Place test-comp inside a template/ng-template tag.

```
<template  #myTemplate>
        <test-comp #refcomp ></test-comp>
 </template>
```

use it wherever you want to display (on the main page and on model pop-up), using below code

```
<div *ngIf="false; else myTemplate"></div>
```